# How to enable stream management in ejabberd server?

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am developing an chat application in android with ejabberd server and smack 4.1.0 beta 2. In that I want to use streammanagement(XEP-0198).

In Installation and operation guide of ejabberd http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.pdf it specified that streammanagement is enabled in default. But it didn't work in my case.

So I manually make streammanagement value as true. But still smack returns false when i call issmavailable() method.

Here is my ejabberd.cfg code,

```
listen,
[
  {5222, ejabberd_c2s, [

                        {access, c2s},

                        {shaper, c2s_shaper},

                        {max_stanza_size, 65536},

                        zlib,

                        starttls,

                        {certfile, "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"},

                        {stream_management,true}

                       ]},
```

Pls help me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

For anybody coming here after an upgrade which disabled XEP-0198: With ejabberd 17.03 the option was renamed and is disabled if not present  at all in the config. The new option is called `mod_stream_mgmt`

https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-17-03/

Answer (score 1):

In ejabberd, stream management is an option of the c2s listener. You should set option `stream_management` to `true`.

Reference is: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#listening-ports

Please, note that on latest ejabberd version, stream management is enabled as default.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I am not getting <sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3’> while connecting to server

Comment: Shouldn't this option enabled by the clients ?

Comment: eJabbered is sending Duplicate message which is already received through FCM so in this case what i have to do please help !!